# Density and the size of coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space, and $F$ a dense subspace spanned by a countable base $y_i$ of unit norm. Let $x \in E$ and $x_n = \sum_{i_n=1}^{N_n} a_{i_n} y_{i_n}$ be a sequence of elements of $E$ converging to $x$.

Is it true in general that the sum $\sum_{i_n=1}^{N_n} |a_{i_n}|$ must remain bounded (by  a constant depending only of $\|x\|$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider a separable Hilbert space with infinite basis $e_n$. Let

$$v=\sum_1^\infty \frac{e_n}{n}.$$

This has norm $\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$, but the sum of the coefficients diverges.

Comment: you beat me to it :). +1

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $\ell_2$, the space of square summable sequences. Let $y_{k}=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$, where the 1 occurs in the $k$'th spot. Take $a_{i_n}=1/i_n$ and $N_n=n$. In other words, $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i}{i}$.  Then $x_n$ converges to $x:=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots)$. This is because

$$\|x_n-x\|_2=\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$$

but clearly $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|=\infty$.